# I need help trying to work with a row accessed from a datatable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-objects

I am trying to get a single row from a data table using LINQ.  It seems to getting the record but I am not able to work with it.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  My LINQ query is below:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
      from myRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
      where myRow.Field<int>("AM2MIN") <= Convert.ToInt32(minimumValue) &&
            myRow.Field<int>("AM2MAX") >= Convert.ToInt32(minimumValue)
      select myRow;
```

When I do the following to see if any records exist, it errors out.

```
if (query.Any())
{

}
```

`InvalidCastException` seems to be the consistent error.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What does it say you're trying to cast it to?

Comment: Another thought, is it possible that the `AM2MIN` field is not actually an `int`?

Comment: What database type is `AM2MIN` and `AM2MAX`.  The invalid cast could be because they are not INT but rather SMALLINT, BIGINT, etc.

Comment: It just says 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of your fields does not contain integer value.

Verify `Data Type` of those columns. Also verify if Nulls are allowed for them. If data type is `int`, but nulls are allowed, then cast to nullable int: `myRow.Field<int?>("AM2MIN")` and verify if it has value.